# TypeScript Function Return Type : What does "obj is Date" mean?

Tags: typescript

I just saw this [TypeScript Code Snippet](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/master/src/runtime/motion/utils.ts)

```js
export function is_date(obj: any): obj is Date {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Date]';
}
```

where I don't understand what `obj is Date` is doing in the function's "return type".

Appreciate if anyone can explain it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as boolean

```
export function is_date(obj: any): boolean {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Date]';
}
```

Read docs about (type-guards) https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

Answer (score 1):

It is similar to boolean but it also restricts the type after the function call :

```
type DateOrString = string | Date

function isDate(dateOrString: DateOrString): dateOrString is Date {
  return date instanceof Date
}
```

Now if you use it in a conditionnal, you get the variable with the restricted type :

```
if(isDate(dateOrString)) {
  // here `dateOrString` is of type Date
}
```